# Passing local vars through a class to a function

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class called timekeeper

```
class TimeKeeper():    
    def __init__(self):
        self.startTick = 0

    def StartClock(self, seconds, ev):
        self.startTick = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.event = ev
    
    def CheckTime(self):
        timePassed = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.startTick)/1000
        if timePassed >= self.seconds and self.startTick != 0:
            self.startTick = 0
            try:
                self.event()
            except:
                pass
        return
```

And in it I pass an event which is a function that is called when a timer ends. However, I found an issue where if this event is a function that takes parameters (e.g. def foo(someVar) )

```
Timer1 = TimeKeeper()
Timer1.StartClock(4, foo)
```

I cant pass parameters through the class so that  theyre called later. I tried adding the parameters inside of the input of the function as follows

```
Timter1.StartClock(4, foo('hello'))
```

but this ends up calling the function when the StartClock function is called rather than when the timer ends. How can I pass a variable through the class to a function without calling it (note that the number of variables may vary)?

Comment: What is the reason you can't pass parameters through the class?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it calls the function immediately if I pass parameters through the class

Comment: You could store the parameters in variables in the class, then use them later when calling the event function in CheckTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo('hello')` calls `foo` *immeidately*, and its return value is passed to `StartClock` to be assigned to `self.event`. You still need to pass a callable that takes 0 arguments; you can do that with a lambda expression

```
Timter1.StartClock(4, lambda: foo('hello'))
```

or `functools.partial`

```
from functools import partial

Timer1.StartClock(4, partial(foo, 'hello'))
```